# How to give an object's all fields visibility to all profiles

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject

I have an object which has around 100 fields now need to give all fields visibility to all the profiles.

One possible solution is to edit each field and give its visibility to all profile but if i opt this i will have to edit all 100 fields.

Is there any centralized place or setting where i can give all these fields visibility to all the profiles without editing each of the fields?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any alternative solution for this. I have the same problem. Infact, you had 1 object I have multiple objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit on profiles instead for that object fields .Go to profiles>field level security and object and click view link and edit .By this process you will be editing number of times the profile rather than number of times the object field